# Después de dar enter sobre un input, no me permite tabular entre los inputs (textbox) en JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, mvc, razor

Activé esos eventos para poder presionar enter cuando estoy situado sobre algún `input` (caja texto) y el botón haga el evento `onclick();` y otro evento para poder tabular entre los `inputs`, pero después de que doy <kbd>Enter</kbd> cuando estoy sobre un `input`, ya no puedo volver a tabular entre ellos, alguna solución?

```
    $("#Login").keyup(function (event) {

        if (event.keyCode == 13) { //Permite dar enter y ejecutar la función, cuando está posicionado sobre el txtLogin
            $("#btnLogin").click();
        }
    });
    $("#Contrasenia").keyup(function (event) {

        if (event.keyCode == 13 ) { //Permite dar enter y ejecutar la función, cuando está posicionado sobre el txtContrasenia
            $("#btnLogin").click();
        }
    });
    $("input").keydown(function (e) { //Permite tabular entre los inputs
        e.which == 9
    });
```

Comment: Podrías proporcionar un fragmento de tu código (html, js) que pueda ser probado para así verificar que puede estar ocurriendo?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creo que te refieres a que una vez se pulse <kbd>Enter</kbd> no se pierda el foco en los *inputs* y sigas pudiendo tabular saltando entre otros inputs del formulario, quedaría algo así:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
// Function for button
  myfoo = function(){
    alert('Hello World');
  };

 $('body').keydown( function(e) {
      switch(e.which){
       case 13: // Enter, use of Function in button
         $(':focus')[0].name == 'txtLogin' ? $("#btnLogin").click() : ''
         $(':focus')[0].name == 'txtcontrasenia' ? $("#btnLogin").click() : ''
        break;
       case 9:  // Tab, use of Alert
         $(':focus')[0].name == 'txtLogin' ? alert( 'Tab Input: ' + $(':focus')[0].name ) : ''
         $(':focus')[0].name == 'txtcontrasenia' ? alert( 'Tab Input: ' + $(':focus')[0].name ) : ''
        break;
        default:
        break;
      }
    }); 
  } );
```

```css
form { display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; }
input { width: 50%; margin-bottom: 3em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <form action="">
    Login <input type="text" id="Login" name="txtLogin">
    Contraseña <input type="text" id="Contrasenia" name="txtcontrasenia">
    <input type="button" id="btnLogin" onclick="myfoo()" value="Boton Login">
  </form>
</body>
```

Todo sin problemas, el foco cuando está en los `input` y se pulsa <kbd>Enter</kbd>, llama al botón y su función, pero no pierde la selección del `input` en el que está y se puede seguir tabulando a partir de ahí.

La tabulación se produce en cascada hacia abajo por todos los elementos de la página, por lo que si buscas que la tabulación sea cerrada, que salte entre *inputs* tipo `text` y vuelva a empezar una vez acabe con el último, habría que hacerlo aparte como parte del script en el caso de la tecla con el *code 9 ( Tabulación )*.

Si apuntas al cuerpo de la página con un solo evento `keydown`, solo con un `switch` o `if/else/elseif` puedes manejar mejor los eventos que quieres que ocurran al pulsar una tecla.

Nota: He usado el operador ternario en los `case`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, funcionó perfecto, cuando daba enter y estaba sobre un textbox se ejecutaba la función del botón, pero como que se perdía el focus, porque aunque me posisionara de forma manual sobre un textbox, ya no funcionaba la tabulación, disculpa que de términos así de textbox, soy nuevo en la parte web, y éstos tipos de controles no los he utilizado mucho, es en razor donde se crean los controles